# dynamic updating of HTML5 canvas

Tags: html, canvas

in the snippet below

```
ctx.clearRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.arc(canvas.width / 2, canvas.height / 2, 143, (startAngle * Math.PI / 180) - Math.PI / 2, 1.5 * Math.PI);
ctx.strokeStyle = "white";
ctx.lineWidth = 14;
ctx.stroke();
```

where i is in multiples of 6,i am not able to update the canvas         every second(using loops), the appearance should be like of a receding clock.
  link to fiddle:https://jsfiddle.net/727q1u7r/3/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/727q1u7r/3/), the code within the loop does not refer to `startAngle`, so each iteration of the loop is drawing exactly the same thing. You probably want to refer to `startAngle` within the arc call.

However this is not enough by itself, a for loop is not suitable for animation, the whole loop will be completed in a flash and you won't see any changes.

You could use [setInterval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowTimers/setInterval) as shown in [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/727q1u7r/4/).

If you are trying to reliably show the system time however, you should look into using [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date) and possibly using [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame).